# Delphi XE4 or XE5: how to open Google Chrome in popup format?

Tags: delphi, google-chrome, popup

Problem: I need to open Google Chrome by Delphi XE5 or XE4 on a given url but I need to open in popup format, without the menus and toolbars. How do?

Comment: Are you sure you want to force the user to a specific browser? If this program is to be sold/released, you should respect the cases that the user does not have Chrome installed, or installed it to a different directory (which you might not know, except when chrome.exe is in the global search path %PATH% ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Chrome process with argument --app and your url

Comment: Okay, but how would this in Delphi? Had a basic example to show me how to create a process of chrome? I could not find anything relevant on Google search how to do it.

Comment: Which search engine are you using? Any good ones will give you a million hits. The two APIs to call are CreateProcess or ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: ok, solved by: ShellExecute(handle, 'open', PChar('chrome.exe'), PChar('--app=www.myurlhere.com'),
    '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Answer (score 2):

silent mode;

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle,'Open', 'chrome.exe',PChar(' -incognito '+URLText), 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```